# JBoss: Do I need Fuse if I have WildFly?

Tags: jboss, cxf, wildfly, jbossfuse

I am trying to follow [this](http://www-stg.jboss.org//quickstarts/fuse/soap/index.html) `JBossDeveloper SOAP web service with Apache CXF` tutorial, but I am stuck right at the beginning as it refers to directories and identifiers **not** in my WildFly/Maven/JDK installation.

So, I am wondering: Do I have at all what I need to follow [this tutorial](http://www-stg.jboss.org//quickstarts/fuse/soap/index.html)? That is, I found this tutorial in the installed WildFly material but the tutorial itself says Fuse is required. I am confused. How is Fuse related to WildFly (if at all)?

---

**Update:** I just read in the official [Fuse Overview](https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/overview/?referrer=jbd) that Fuse actually contains CXF, not WildFly. So it appears that the tutorial expects to download Fuse instead of CXF, not instead of the application server. Do I understand this correctly now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss Fuse and Wildfly and different products altogether. If you need to check and have CXF tutorial, you can refer to the link you referred for Fuse, but for EAP, the configuration for CXF is different. 
For CXF in wildfly, you can refer to this tutorial here, https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JAX-WS+User+Guide.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of guidance I needed. Thank you!